# How many cron can run together of same groups in magento 2

Tags: magento2, aws, magento-cron, cronjobs

I want to know how many crons of the same group and different groups are run parallel in Magento 2.

As we have too many crons our cron execution is failing and missed execution.
We have already 11 to 12 different groups other than the default cron group.

We are facing an issue with a long-running cron that impacts the next scheduled cron.